# Query to get duplicate records in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, distinct

How to get duplicate records from table when combined with two Columns.

My Table Values:

```
UserId     ProgramId 
100          1 
100          1 
100          1 
100          2 
101          2 
101          2 
100          3 
101          3 
102          4 
102          4 
103          5
```

Desired Output:

```
UserId      ProgramId 
100          1 
100          2 
100          3 
101          2 
101          3
```

I tried the below query to get the duplicate values of UserId for distinct ProgramID in the table.

```
SELECT [UserId],[ProgramId],COUNT([UserId]) FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY [UserId],[ProgramId]
HAVING COUNT([UserId]) > 1
order by [UserId]
```

I am getting the UserId, ProgramId and Count of Duplicate rows but not specified for distinct ProgramId. What is the mistake in my query ??. Any suggestions will be mostly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can use the following query to get the result.  This uses a CTE to generate the list of `userids` that have multiple distinct `programids`. Once you have that then you can use this to join back to your table to get the combination of `userid` and `programid`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select userid
  from table1
  group by userid
  having count(distinct programid) > 1
) 
select distinct c.userid, t.programid
from cte c
inner join table1 t
  on c.userid = t.userid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a904/2)

Answer (score 1):

You are counting on one of the same columns that you are grouping by, that's always going to be one(1).

Try it like this instead:

```
SELECT   [UserId],[ProgramId],COUNT(*)
FROM     [Table1]
GROUP BY [UserId],[ProgramId]
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
order by [UserId]
```

Of course a `DISTINCT` would do the same thing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         [UserId],[ProgramId]
FROM     [Table1]
order by [UserId]
```

..since `DISTINCT` is really just a simplified `GROUP BY`, but then it's not as expandable/editable.  and since I assume that you want to do more with it than just what we see here ...